# Store audio signal into array using matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, audio

I recorded an audio signal (.wav) and I need to convert this signal into a matrix or array using matlab, so i can add it to another one.

```
[x,fs] = wavread('C:\Users\Amira\Desktop\test222.wav');

fs=44100

length(x) = 339968
```

How can i sample this signal and covert it to matrix of (N,1) where N=40.

Comment: Why do you only want 40 samples from your input signal?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the first 40 samples of your audio signal, you can simply index into `x`:

```
[x,fs] = wavread('C:\Users\Amira\Desktop\test222.wav');
first40 = x(1:40);
```